# printf not printing last character

Tags: c, printf, trim

I'm making a simple code for simulating Caesar's cypher and I'm having a weird bug where, although the output string `fraseout[]` is formed correctly and will print correctly at the very last print it gets it's last character trimmed. Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
int main (void)
{
        printf("Insira a frase:\n");
        char frase [256];
        scanf("%s", frase);
        int size = (int)strlen(frase);
        printf("Insira o tamanho da divergência: \n");
        int diff = 0;
        scanf("%i", &diff);
        char fraseout [size];
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i<=size-1; i++)
        {
                int val = (int)frase[i];
                if (val + diff > 126)
                {
                        val = 31+diff-(126-val);
                }
                else if (val +diff < 32)
                {
                        val = 127 + diff+(val-32);
                }
                else
                {
                        val +=diff;
                }
                fraseout [i] = (char)val;
        }

        printf("\"%s\" -> \"%s\"\n", frase, fraseout);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: what your debugger tells you?

Comment: Use `int size = (int)strlen(frase) + 1;`

Comment: `char fraseout [size];` -> `char fraseout [size+1];` and you didn't terminate `fraseout`.

Comment: You might like to read about C-"string"s, about the infamous `0`-termination they rely on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fraseout` is not long enough to hold the NULL terminating byte, so you need to make it one bigger:

```
char fraseout [size+1];
```

Also, after building `fraseout`, you need to make sure it's NULL terminated, otherwise you'll print garbage:

```
fraseout[size] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two related points,

1. Need to take the size as `strlen()`+ 1, as `strlen()` does not take into account the terminating null.
2. Need to make the `fraseout[i]`, the last element as `0` or `'\0'` to make it usable as a *string*.